# Lambda function behavior with schedule event after deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, aws-event-bridge

So, at first, I deploy my function with config like this for debugging purposes

```
...
functions:
  myFunc:
    handler: myFunc.handler
    timeout: 300
    events:
      - schedule:
          name: event-name
          description: "event-name description"
          rate: rate(10 minute)
...
```

Then, I decided to change **schedule rate** to **1 day**

I got 2 questions:

- Will the event be called every day from the moment of deployment or from the last 10 minutes trigger?
- After the next deployment, the event's execution time will remain the same, or will start from the time of deployment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html#RateExpressions):

> A rate expression **starts when you create the scheduled event rule**, and then runs on its defined schedule.

After update, the **rule stays the same**, unless your update changes the rule. CloudFormation does not re-deploy resource which do not change when a resource is not affected by the update process.